# Wordpress PHP 7.0 to 7.3 Wordpress on gcp

Tags: php, wordpress

I already updated php to 7.3 and did following commands

```
sudo a2dismod php7.0

sudo a2enmod php7.3
```

and restarted apache2.

Then my site just showed `Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.`

So I started php.7.0 again, and it runs as usual.

How can I fix the MySQL extension Problem, so that I can update to 7.3?

WordPress Version 5.4.2 on Debian.

Thanks you!